# How do I move fields of data from all documents in one collection into new documents of a different collection?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

**My Situation**: I created an Mongo (mongoose), Express, and Node app and now that I'm building additional features, I've realized my models won't handle the new features, so I built a new model that's future proof, but I need to move some fields of data from my old model, User, to my new model, List.

What is the best way of moving document data from all of a specific field within one collection of documents into a new document within a new collection? Can I create a script with JavaScript and run it against my server or database?

I don't want to disrupt my users' experience, if all possible. Also, I know there is the db.collection.update method, but I need to move all this data all at once, not whenever I run that method in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script it in many ways, but it's probably simplest to:

1. Use [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with an [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage at the end of the pipeline to populate a new collection from the original documents. Use a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in the pipeline to structure the output documents as desired.
2. Use [`updateMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) on the original collection to remove the "moved" fields using the [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator.

Depending on the specifics of your system, you may still need to take the users offline while you do this.

Comment: I've read the docs on this and it seems like the right solution, but I have a question - how do I use $out to move the data into the new model, List, collection if I haven't used the model yet, which means the collection doesn't currently exist. I want to make sure when I move all this data, It will be in the same collection when I start using my new model, List.

Comment: Correct answer!